# Blue transparent rectangular box with solid outline appeared on boot today and won't go away

Tags: boot, screen, monitor

Upon booting into the computer for the first time today, a blue rectangular box that's transparent blue inside with a solid blue outline. Picture attached.
I rebooted and realized that the box is there as soon as the computer screen flashes the Asus brand name for the motherboard. Yesterday, some software updates were installed, but I'm not sure if that was a cause or coincidence. I've gone into settings, I've used bleachbit to remove broken software and unnecessary files, none of it has worked so far. Is it possible that my monitor is the problem? Is anyone else with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS having this issue?

Comment: The image you attached is not related to your problem.

Comment: The image provided has *nothing* to do with your issue.  The screenshot (now removed) is showcasing a feature of the Ask Ubuntu site which is specifically used to emphasize where on the page you have focus on.  What is the *actual* issue you're facing?

Comment: the blue rectangle in the screenshot is the problem. I cannot get rid of it and have no ideal where it cam from. It stays on the same place on the screen no matter how far I scroll.

Comment: As there is no blue rectangle on the screenshot, it may be your monitor that's at fault. Can you take a picture with your phone or something like that?